# Books/resources to help understand Component Object Model using C#?

Tags: c#, com

Please suggest any good books for learning how to use Component Object Model (COM) from C#.

Comment: Why do you want to learn COM? It's rather outdated.

Comment: I don't think there is much point to using managed code to interact with unmanaged code.  Pick up a book on C or C++.

Comment: This is an important (even if not exactly a good question). Dealing with COM from C# can be very tricky to "get right" and there seems to be very little concise information on lifetimes -- especially when RCW/CCW's are introduced. Also finer details like Connection Points are even harder to find information on. (The post is "how to use" COM from C# and not "should I use COM from C#?")

Comment: @Woot4Moo I think there is much point. It allows for minimal stubs to be written in unmanaged code, exposed as COM, and used seamlessly with the bulk of the managed program. I am much more productive at C# than ATL C++. One really nice feature of COM is to be able to run out-of-process which can simplify issues like using MAPI "from within" an Outlook add-in.

Comment: @Sunny: do you want to learn COM, but you want to use C# to do COM, or do you already use COM and you just want to learn how to access COM from C#?

Comment: @john:Yes i want to learn COM using C#. Actually i am a java programmer that's why i am comfortable with C#.

Comment: @Sunny: then I'm back to my recommendation: you don't want to learn COM at all. COM is no longer a recommended development methodology.

Comment: Then What is the alternative of it do i get the enough of the classes from the .NET framework itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have (or know of) a book on this subject.

One invaluable resource I have used is the .NET Interoperability information found on MSDN: [Interoperating with Unmanaged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It covers the overview, a number of general interoperability details, and how to expose COM to .NET and .NET to COM. For a general COM resource, however, it is rather sparse.

Happy coding.